# Are Turtle Charge Stations as inefficient as they seem?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

The [wiki](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Charge_Station) states that Charge Stations refuel Turtles at a rate of 1EU\t. Some quick math shows this is 20 fuel per second, 1200 fuel per minute. I can give a turtle 1000 fuel instantly using a bucket of lava. Is there some convienience or trick with the Charge Stations that I'm missing here, or should I continue to manually fill my Turtles with lava?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a charge station is that a turtle can be self-refueling. This is useful for self-contained turtle "machines".

For example, if you have a turtle minding a tree farm, it can sit comfortably in its charge station while in its wait loop, and be fully charged when it gets to its "go around the farm and check the trees" code section. If its code isn't buggy and the charge station's power supply is reliable, it could happily run indefinitely without manual refueling.

Of course, there aren't very many obvious uses for unmonitored turtles, since there are so many other ways of automating processes in FTB. If you have a "pet" turtle that you carry around with you and only set down for specific tasks while you're nearby, then yes, manual fueling makes much more sense.